# What is difference Javax.jws and javax.xml.ws

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am new to Java and trying to jump into WebServices. I found two examples somewhere and I am confused with the available options.

Firstly, `javax.jws.WebService` with annotation seem to work fine, but there is loads of material on `javax.xml.ws`. It seems `javax.jws` is newer and there is not much material available about it.

What is the difference between these two approaches?

Comment: Posterity, https://coderanch.com/t/434727/certification/Difference-WebService-WebServiceProvider-annotation

Answer (score 13):

#### Web Services Metadata Annotations (JSR 181)

Using annotations from the JSR 181 specification (**`java.jws.xxx`**), you can annotate a Web service implementation class or a Web service interface.

e.g. from [*Deploy JAX-WS Web Services On Tomcat*](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/)

```
package com.mkyong.ws;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

//Service Endpoint Interface
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface HelloWorld{

    @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString();

}
```

#### JAX-WS 2.0 Annotations (JSR 224)

The JSR 224 specification defines annotations for JAX-WS 2.0 (**`javax.xml.ws.xxx`**).

e.g. from [*Using SOAP Faults and Exceptions in Java JAX-WS*](http://io.typepad.com/eben_hewitt_on_java/2009/07/using-soap-faults-and-exceptions-in-java-jaxws-web-services.html)

```
@WebFault(name="CheckVerifyFault",
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com")
public class CheckVerifyFault extends Exception {

    /**
     * Java type that goes as soapenv:Fault detail element.
     */
    private CheckFaultBean faultInfo;

    public CheckVerifyFault(String message, CheckFaultBean faultInfo) {
        super(message);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public CheckVerifyFault(String message, CheckFaultBean faultInfo, 
                               Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public CheckFaultBean getFaultInfo() {
        return faultInfo;
    }
}
```

---

[Peer Reynders](http://www.coderanch.com/t/222523/Web-Services/java/JSR-JSR) says:

> My guess would be that BEA wanted something NOW to put into Weblogic to compete with the equivalent feature in .NET. (see, developing Web services in WebLogic is just "as easy"). Also the annotations specified in JAX-WS 2.0 (JSR-224) <strike>seem</strike> to provide you with more control. However JSR-224 does explicitly support/include JSR-181 (JSR-224: 7.10 Annotations Defined by JSR-181).

For a more complete discussion about, see [JSR 181: a Java Simplification Request](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJun2007.html)

See also:

- [Annotations references](http://jonas.ow2.org/JONAS_5_1_1/doc/doc-en/html/jaxws_developer_guide.html#jaxws-annotations-reference)
- [JAX-WS annotations reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.webservice.doc/topics/jaxws/rwsandoc003.html)
- [JSR 181](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=181)
- [JSR 224](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224)

Answer (score 6):

These two package namespaces **do not** define different approaches.

- If you're creating services based on the Web, there are two options: SOAP services (AKA Web services) or REST services (AKA RESTful services).
- If implementing SOAP services in Java, the way to go is to use the JAX-WS framework. The framework provides tools, such as wsimport and wsgen, and of course an API.
- The JAX-WS API includes annotations, classes and interfaces for implementing the code of a SOAP service itself and the code of a service consumer (the client).
- Altogether these elements of the JAX-WS API use both `javax.xml.ws` and `javax.jws` package namespaces.
- Just follow the tutorials or examples to create the services using JAX-WS. Don't worry about which packages do the API elements come from.
- But remember to avoid vendor specific API elements. You're more likely to run into these vendor specific elements when using WS-* standards (e.g., WS-Security) beyond WSDL and SOAP.

Comment: They **do** define different approaches, check this https://coderanch.com/t/434727/certification/Difference-WebService-WebServiceProvider-annotation