# How to use WebServices on Java 11? package javax.jws does not exist

Tags: java, java-11

I imigrate my aplication to AdoptOpenJDK11, I have found some problems, like "package javax.jws does not exist", I already configure build path with jar "jsr181-api.jar", it's a webApplication, how I fix it ? Have something new about webservices on AdoptOpenJDK 11?

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC) // this tags doenst work

output:
error: package javax.jws does not exist
error: package javax.jws.soap does not exist
```

Someone know how I fix it?

Answer (score 61):

Per  [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis)

Use the reference implementation of JAX-WS instead.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I believe there are two different things: javax.jws belongs to JSR-181 and javax.xml.ws (which is included in jaxws-ri ) belongs to JSR-224.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212246/what-is-difference-javax-jws-and-javax-xml-ws/25766828

Comment: NexusIQ complains for version 2.3.0 so we used 2.3.2