# Migration to Jakarta: ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl

Tags: soap, java-11, jakarta-ee

While migrating from Java 8 to Java 11 and switching from EE to the newest Jakarta libraries according to https://wiki.eclipse.org/New_Maven_Coordinates and Maven central, we get the following runtime exception in our (still SOAP-based) client application:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:31)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:28)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.newInstance(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:73)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:82)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:66)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:82)
        at [...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:60)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:93)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.newInstance(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:71)
        ... 5 more
```

The solution described in [Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl despite the dependencies are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107375/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-spi-providerim) doesn't work and doesn't use Jakarta.

If I'm not wrong, the Jarkarta libraries shouldn't contain "com.sun.xml."packages or reference such, but *javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider* obviously STILL DOES reference such class:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_JAXWSPROVIDER =
        "com.sun"+".xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl";
```

So, does anyone know if there is a Jakarta equivalent to the missing library containing ProviderImpl, or how I could workaround the problem with Jakarta?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found a workaround for my problem. According to the answer given in [How to use WebServices on Java 11? package javax.jws does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516361/how-to-use-webservices-on-java-11-package-javax-jws-does-not-exist) the reference implementation of *JAX-WS* should be included with Java 11:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately, compiling our project with this dependency using the latest maven-compile-plugin 3.8.0 causes the exception described in https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-355. It should be fixed in 3.8.1 but the version is not available yet.

As a workaround I got our project working with the hint given in [Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl despite the dependencies are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107375/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-spi-providerim), combined with an additional dependency (namely *resolver* that is also linked in the *pom.xml* of *jaxws-ri*) to avoid an subsequent *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogManager*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
    <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
    <version>20050927</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe this helps someone running into the same problem.

Comment: Greetings! I just ran into this issue myself and tried your workaround but still am having issues. Any updates on how to fix this exact issue? I tried using all different kinds of dependencies and versions but the Provider.class still points to the wrong ProviderImpl.class. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Throwing my 5 cents into the ring as I had "the same problem". What resolved it to me was to stick with the version two of the jaxws-rt package, since version 3.0.0 did fail with the same results as mentioned above.

So what I used to get my JDK 8 source running without any modification was:

```java
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-rt', version: '2.3.3' //3.0.0 did not work!

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-api', version: '2.3.1'
    
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jws/javax.jws-api
    implementation group: 'javax.jws', name: 'javax.jws-api', version: '1.1'
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the only solution that worked for me!