# I can't use HtmlUnitDriver with Maven in my JavaFX project

Tags: java, maven, javafx, htmlunit-driver

I'm trying to use HtmlUnitDriver in my JavaFX project but when I add HtmlUnitDriver I get these Errors
I tried different version and still same error I dont know what to do

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.utils.PrefixResolver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.utils.PrefixResolver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 45 more
```

There is Just one Class in my JavaFX project

the class Main.java contains this code below

```
  package com.ali.chegg.chegg;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        
 AnchorPane p=new AnchorPane();
                Label lbl = new Label("Title);
                Button b=new Button("get title");
                b.setLayoutX(100);
                b.setOnAction((t) -> {
                 HtmlUnitDriver d=new HtmlUnitDriver();
                 d.get("https://www.google.com");
                 lbl.setText(d.getTitle());
                });
                p.getChildren().addAll(lbl,b);
        scene = new Scene(p,640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
 
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 
             
        launch(args);

    }

}
```

and POM.xml file:

```
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ali.chegg</groupId>
    <artifactId>Chegg</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.ali.chegg.chegg.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

btw I'm using Apache NetBeans 11.3 and jdk 14.0.1

Comment: You can find something usefull here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319199/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-org-apache-xml-internal-resolver-catal