# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/CatalogManager

Tags: java, xml, java-8, jaxb, java-11

In Java 8 to 11 migration, I am getting  migration java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/CatalogManager

```
tried adding below, but its not working
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
    <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
    <version>20050927</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogManager Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319199/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-org-apache-xml-internal-resolver-catal)